# How can I simulate content type inheritance in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I've been asked to create several content types that similar, and some that are the same.

For example:
Tutorial & Video Tutorial, they're almost the same, but the Video Tutorial has the video id.

Another example:
How To Article, Overview Article, etc ... they're all exactly the same (for now anyway), so I'd like to create a single Article type, and basically 'inherit' it somehow.

Can I create an 'IS A' relationship between different types?

Am I asking the wrong question and I should be doing something different?

Or should I just copy & paste the AlterTypeDefinition() multiple times in my migration file? With the richness of Orchard, I'm assuming copy & pasting types isn't the way it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create several different content types, Orchard is all about being able to reuse the parts and fields you make for different content types. No reason why you cant have a bunch of similar but slightly different content types.

For your article content type, as they are the same, have you considered using Taxonomies to classify your articles? So create a taxonomy of ArticleType with all your different article types: How To Article, Overview Article, etc. Create a Article content type and attach a taxonomy field linking to ArticleType so when you create an article there will be a list of available articletypes to classify said article as. Can easily add more later if the need should arise.

Comment: I did consider your taxonomy idea, but felt the 'IS A' relationship might be better.  Is that how you would do it?  With Taxonomies?

Comment: Yeah that is how I have done it before, I cant think of any way to do the 'is a' relationship. But I mean if you think content types may change in the future then just create separate content types, it shouldn't present much more work really, or much more overhead.

Comment: Orchard is architected around composition, not inheritance. In your example, isolate the commonalities between your content types into a common `Tutorial` content part. Same thing for articles: common properties go onto common parts.